# HTML4+5 jquery ajax history without changing URL, hashbang?

Tags: jquery, html, browser-history, html4

Trying to get a browser back/forward and reload going on ajax content, where the actions that load the content are not typical has links (e.g. not `<a href='#foo.html'>`, like you see in the http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-bbq/examples/fragment-basic/#kielbasa.html examples).

Been looking at various history libraries that all seem to implement based on the hashchange. e.g. Address : http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/, or History.js : https://github.com/browserstate/history.js - but I can't work out how to make these work if the hash ISN'T changing.

My content page is called "content.html" and it never gets a hash change. Any clue on how to implement a history / refresher that works in IE7+ where there's no has change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not quite understand what you need, but can this library will work just as you need: https://github.com/devote/HTML5-History-API

Comment: my need was that the URL never changes, actions other than clicks cause things to load on the page that you should be able to press back/forward against, in IE7 or better. refreshing the page should re-load the current state.

Comment: I think I got it. Basically I'm pushing the value I want to store to the state, and not storing a changed href at all - just the current one `history.pushState( {id: thisId}, null, location.href);` and then looking to see if `history.state` has an id on the popstate event and executing what needs to happen with that value. Seems good so far

Comment: Can you give an example of what you do, what I could see a more complete problem. Thanks

Comment: >> press back/forward against, in IE7 or better. refreshing the page should re-load the current state
------
hmm .. I understand you need to keep track of the event `popstate`